# How to find WHICH key is pressed c++

Tags: c++, windows

I want to make a button which will record the immediate next key the user will press ( just the first one ) 
i have tried this

```
int whichKeyPressed()
{
while (true)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 0x8000) {
            while (GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 0x8000) {
                Sleep(50);
            }
            return i;
        }
    }
    Sleep(10);
  }
}
```

but it returns some random numbers . ( it returns 64 for A , 65 for B and so on . )

Comment: The number returned is the virtual key code for the key that has been pressed. If you want a human-readable representation, you can translate the key code into a character using the MapVirtualKey function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: so you mean if i put the code in a getasyncstate it will detect the key ? but i cant read it ?

Comment: *64 for A "a random number"* - they are so cute when they are young... ;-)

Comment: im 18 :) and with random i meant numbers that i dont know if they have a meaning.but thank you :) i know im cute

Comment: The following example code should output an 'a' when you press the A key, a 'b' for the B key, etc. `std::cout << (char)MapVirtualKey(whichKeyPressed(), MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR);` If you want to compare the key code to a specific key, here is a list of all virtual key codes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: 64 sounds like an off-by-one-error. How "random" this is? - See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: it works . thank you but is there anway to convert ascii to virtual key codes?

Comment: johannes ,i saw that before. but  it returns 255 for click1 and many other numbers .

Comment: "is there anway to convert ascii to virtual key codes" - `VkKeyScanEx`.